# How can i generate overlay for weather api on MKMapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, overlay

I don't have idea about overlay.I am stuck at this point.I am integration one of Weather API and it returns me several values now i want see all that value on the mapView it self so i need to integrate overlay on the mapView.Please help me how can i add overlay for displaying weather information on the MapView?.I am receiving this kind of response.

{"weatherObservation":{"clouds":"n/a","weatherCondition":"n/a","observation":"VOBL 240600Z 09011KT 060V130 CAVOK 24/03 Q1018 NOSIG","windDirection":90,"ICAO":"VOBL","elevation":915,"countryCode":"IN","lng":77.7,"temperature":"24","dewPoint":"3","windSpeed":"11","humidity":25,"stationName":"BENGALURU","datetime":"2012-01-24 06:00:00","lat":13.2,"hectoPascAltimeter":1018}}

[image]

I want to show this kind of effect on my MapView using overlay.

Comment: you should first tell us what kind of information u want to display and also what is the information u are getting from ur weather API. May be u can paste the response of the api and show us a sample image to go with. For sample image u can check out the images on google or http://www.met.ie/

Comment: I am receiving the above response and i want to show this information on my Mapview using Overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MKMapKit provides MKPolygon class and add overlay to achieve this. This can be done with easy four steps

1. Initialize map
2. Get coordinates
3. Create Polygon and add to map.
4. Implement delegate

For more detail see [here](http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/iphoneipad-adding-overlay/)